# LightGBMError: Do not support special JSON characters in feature name

Tags: python, lightgbm

I am new to machine learning and I have checked the answers online but didnt found the exact solution.

```
from math import sqrt 
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_log_error
import lightgbm as lgb
train_data = lgb.Dataset(X_train, label=y_train)
test_data = lgb.Dataset(X_cv, label=y_cv)

param = {'objective': 'regression',
         'boosting': 'gbdt',
         'num_iterations': 3000,   
         'learning_rate': 0.06,  
         'num_leaves': 40,  
         'max_depth': 24,   
         'min_data_in_leaf':11,  
         'max_bin': 4, 
         'metric': 'l2_root'
         }
param = np.array(param)
lgbm = lgb.train(params=param,
                 verbose_eval=1000,
                 train_set=train_data,
                 valid_sets=[test_data])
```

Answer (score 1):

The provided example is not reproducible because it does not contain code to create `X_train`, y_train, `X_cv`, and `y_cv`.

However, the error message cited can be reproduced with the following, using `lightgbm` 3.1.1 and Python 3.8.

```py
import lightgbm as lgb
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


X = pd.DataFrame({
    "x,1": np.random.random(100),
    "x_2": np.random.random(100)
})

y = np.random.random(100)

reg = lgb.LGBMRegressor()
reg.fit(X, y)
```

This error message is saying that characters like `,` which have special meaning in JSON cannot be used in feature names.

To avoid this error, remove any of these characters from feature names:

- `,`
- `]`
- `[`
- `{`
- `}`
- `"`
- `:`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have forbidden characters in feature names. Please try to cast your data to numpy array:

```py
train_data = lgb.Dataset(X_train.to_numpy(), label=y_train)
test_data = lgb.Dataset(X_cv.to_numpy(), label=y_cv)
```

Numpy array hasn't the feature names so the training should start.